# JMSTimestamp Vs Other Date storing headers on a JMS message

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I'm using AMQs REST API to send a message to a Queue with a header set in the queryString.

I'm setting a date header `myDateHeader` with the millisecond value of a UNIX timestamp.

`&myDateHeader=1583781133771`

The `JMSTimestamp` header is being set automatically for me, and also seems to be set as a long....

I then consume this message with camel, albeit in Talend, and can 'parse' the `JMSTimestamp` to a formatted date.

However when I try to do the same with `myDateHeader` I get `null` back.

Both `JMSTimestamp` and `myDateHeader` show values if I 'parse' to `String` and `Long` so something is (not) happening as part of the date parsing.

Talend code shows

```
row5.Event_Timestamp = org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder
                            .simple("${in.header.myDateHeader}")
                            .evaluate(routerExchange, java.util.Date.class);
```

showing the correct `resultType` as per the `SimpleBuilder` class. The code is the same as that generated for parsing the `JMSTimestamp`.

Also when I try

`simple("${date:in.header.myDateHeader:yyyyMMdd}")`

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find java.util.Date object at command: in.header.myDateHeader
```

I'm guessing:

1) that when the message is created, the header needs to be set with a correct type of `Date` to be able to do this date parsing as part of consumption?

2) And that the REST API sets all headers with type `String` and I can't change this through my REST call?

Excuse my guesses but am hoping if someone can confirm the above, and therefore that I can't treat `myDateHeader` the same as the `JMSTimestamp` header when consuming these messages?

thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't believe there is any way to set the type of a header via the REST management API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second assumption is correct. Custom headers are parsed with type `String`. In Talend, as well as in Apache Camel, which is a Talend ESB's underlying integration framework, the predefined JMS headers including `JMSTimestamp` are converted to Java types according to [the "Message format when receiving" reference table](https://help.talend.com/reader/8avcOyufaVYo7Uoah0kOlA/QePbiae0L07j9XuKxKUltA).